# Razor page redirect to another folder page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm facing an issue with razor page navigation. I'm in the https://localhost:7154/Application/setupAccount page and i have to redirect to https://localhost:7154/Loan/setupLoan page.

So I used RedirectToPage("setupLoan", new{id=123}. but the issue is that it's looking like a setupLoan page inside the Application folder. ( URL - https://localhost:7154/Application/setupLoan )
Then I'm getting an error like page not found

I can use redirect functionality. But the thing is, I can't send dynamic query parameters.
So let me know if anyone know a correct path to navigate razor page into another folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
   return RedirectToPage("setupLoan", new { area = "Application",id=1 });
```

result:

[image]

You can read [Areas with Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-7.0#areas-with-razor-pages) to know more.

**Update**

```
 return RedirectToPage("setupLoan", new { area = "Loan",id=1 });
```

**Update 2**

Loan is a page folder. not area folder ,
try:

```
  return RedirectToPage("/Loan/setupLoan", new { id = 1 });
```

Comment: @Harendrra , Please have a look at my asnwer. Hope it can help you.

Comment: Hi @Qing,
It's navigating to /Application/setupLoan. i need to navigate it to /Loan/setupLoan

Comment: @Harendrra Is Loan an area folder name ?

Comment: Is a setupLoan page inside the Loan folder ?

Comment: Yes @Qing Guo
Loan is a different area folder, and setupLoan is in that folder

Comment: @Harendrra Try my update.

Comment: It's not working. My bad, Loan is a page folder. not area folder

Comment: @Harendrra , ok , try the update2 . If not work , could you share you folder structure ?